# sed command and formatting one line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to turn these headers:

```
'>>tr|G1PEZ0|G1PEZ0_MYOLU Uncharacterized protein (Fragment) OS=Myotis lucifugus GN=SNCG PE=4 SV=1
```

into just this:

```
'>G1PEZ0_MYOLU
```

Please ignore the apostrophe at the beginning.

Comment: Well, in this particular case I'd try `s/^\(.\).*|\([^ ]*\).*$/\1\2/` but I don't know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Does the output contain one `>`?

Comment: `awk -F'[| ]' '{sub(/>tr/,""); print $1$3}'`

Comment: @jasonwryan submit that as an answer! much better than my piped `awk`s (-:

Comment: thank you all for the quick responses. Bananguin's code seems have done the trick. I can't believe I spent so much time trying to do this myself.

Comment: @jasonwryan: The question is tagged with `sed` though :D

Comment: @Bananguin Yes: I can see that; that is why I didn't write up my solution (even though `awk` is a valid approach) as an answer. Further, for [tag:text-processing] questions, we tend to tolerate if not encourage multiple approaches...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
str='>>tr|G1PEZ0|G1PEZ0_MYOLU Uncharacterized protein (Fragment) OS=Myotis lucifugus GN=SNCG PE=4 SV=1'
echo "$str" | sed -e 's/ .*//' -e 's/.*|//' -e 's/^/>/'
```

That uses 3 separate substitutions - delete everything from the 1st space on the line onwards, delete everything up to the last `|` on the line, and put a `>` back as the first character of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using `cut`:

```
input=">>tr|G1PEZ0|G1PEZ0_MYOLU Uncharacterized protein (Fragment) OS=Myotis lucifugus GN=SNCG PE=4 SV=1"
echo "$input" | cut -d" " -f1 | cut -d"|" -f3 | sed "s/^/>/"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tr` and `cut`:

```
tr ' |' '>>' <input |cut -d\> -f1,6
```

...which `tr`ansforms all spaces and `|`pipes into `>` right-angles, then `cut`s out from among the resultant `> -d`elimited `-f`ields only the 1st and 6th.

With sed...

```
sed -n 'y/ /\n/;s/.*|/>/;P' <input
```

Which also `y///` transforms all spaces into `\n`ewlines, then `s///`ubstitutes the left-most and longest string that it can which ends with a `|`pipe into a single `>` then `P`rints only up to the first `\n`ewline in pattern space.